# помогите пожалуйста! нужно чтобы не выводились повторяющиеся элементы массива, не получается это сделать

Tags: c++, массивы

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int fun(const int*a, const int n, int x);
int main() {
    setlocale(0, "");
    const int N = 10; int A[N];
    int i, j, k;
    cout << "Введите массив:" << endl;
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
        cin >> A[i];
    cout << "Результаты:" << endl;
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++){
        cout << A[i] << ' ' << fun(A, N, i) << endl;
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
int fun(const int*a, const int n, int x){
    int k=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
       if (a[x] == a[i])
          k++;
    return k;
}
```

Comment: Неужели сделать скриншот проще, чем скопировать код в текст вопроса?

Comment: хотите чтобы помогли, тогда  потрудитесь оформлять вопрос по правилам. Этот код скопируйте в вопрос

Comment: set  для кого придумали?

Answer (score 0):

Эту задачу можно решать многими способами, но придержусь вашему подходу и стараюсь внести в ваш код минимум изменений, и если я правильно понимаю, то вам не нужно выводить в упорядоченном виде.  Идея в том, что если хотите знать, был ли использован такой же элемент, то
вам нужно держать еще один массив такого же размера беззнакого типа, где будет записано количество встречающихся элементов массива с соответствующим индексом. Если встретился элемент с таким же значением, то записывается ноль. Тогда в функцию нужно передать этот массив, и задача функции становится  записью в этот массив и ничего не возвращать:

```
void fun(const int* a, const int n, unsigned* b) {  
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
        int k = 1;
        if (b[i]) {    //такое число не встретилось         
           for (int j = i + 1; j < n; ++j)          
                if (a[i] == a[j]) {
                    ++k;
                    b[j] = 0;
                }          
           b[i] = k;           
        }       
    }   
}
int main()
{
    setlocale(0, "");
    const int N = 10; int A[N];
    unsigned B[N];
    cout << "Введите массив:" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        cin >> A[i];
        B[i] = 1; // изначально допускаем, что все элементы уникальны
    }
    fun(A, N, B); //теперь в В записаны все данные
    cout << "Результаты:" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {       
        if (B[i])
          cout << A[i] << ' ' << B[i] << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Как вы видите функция вызывается только один раз, а не в каждом цикле как у вас,  зато в массиве `В` будут записаны нужные нам данные...